# Validate dropdown from 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Sheet 1 has column A called CONTRACTOR
Sheet 2 contains CONTRACTOR details. Column A has Company Name, Column B has Contact Name

If I start type a name in column A on Sheet 1, how would I get autofill to show either column A and/or column B from Sheet 2?

I would like the dropdown to contain both the Company Name and Contact Name if available, or just show either A or B if only one is available.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Add an auxiliary column to concatenate the values of the two columns, then use the result as reference for the data validation

## Explanation

To concatenate the values of two columns use a formula like the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B3&IF(LEN(Sheet1!B1:B3)*LEN(Sheet1!C1:C3)>0," ","")&Sheet1!C1:C3))
```

`IF(LEN(Sheet1!B1:B3)*LEN(Sheet1!C1:C3)>0," ","")`: The purpose of this part is to avoid the inclusion of unnecessary separators.

Once that you have an auxiliary column withe the values, use the correspondent range reference on the Data validation settings.

## References

- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)

Comment: Thanks for this. I am having a little trouble editing this formula.   Here is what I have:

=ARRAYFORMULA(Sites!A2:A136&IF(LEN(Sites!B2:B136)*LEN(Sites!B2:B136)>0,", ","")&Sites!B2:B136)

and some of the results:

High Street Mall, 3122 Mount Lehman Rd
, 33550 South Fraser Way 
Shelter Modular, 3294 262nd Street

So Lines 1 & 3 are what I want, Line 2 would be great if I could eliminate the comma and space before the address.

Cheers

Comment: Please edit your question to include the content of your comment.